# django window popup with table details

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, django

I want to create a button in the template that if i press **View** i want a popup to show up and in that popup i want to display my Table from models.py.

Basically i want that popup to have all the columns names and the all the date of that tabled display. with pagination if its possible.

This is part of my **seaerch_table.html**

```
<script>
    $("#mytable").dialog({autoOpen: false});
    $("#opener").click(function () {
        $("#mytable").dialog("open");
    });
</script>

    <table class="table table-bordered sortable table-hover" id="mytable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Url</th>
            <th>View All Info</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for lists in details %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ lists.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ lists.title }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ lists.url }}" target="_blank">{{ lists.url }}</a></td>
                <td>
                    <button id="opener">View</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

It only shows in the template only 3 fields...and i want to add 2 more field when i do the popup which will include the **Created***at and **Descriptions** field. I don't want to do nothing special on that popup...just display the entire table from mysql (which include the column created*at and **description**)

Can someone please help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$( function() {
$( "#dialog1" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
show: {
  effect: "blind",
  duration: 1000,
  width: "auto", 
  height: "auto",
  position: "left", 

},
hide: {
  effect: "explode",
  duration: 1000,
  width: "auto", 
  height: "auto",
  position: "left",
}
});

$( "#opener1" ).on( "click", function() {
$( "#dialog1" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
```

html:

```
<p id="opener1" style="color:green; margin: 0%">show table</p>
<div id="dialog1" title="Number of entry failed.">
<table class="table table-bordered sortable table-hover" id="mytable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Url</th>
        <th>View All Info</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for lists in details %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ lists.id }}</td>
            <td>{{ lists.title }}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ lists.url }}" target="_blank">{{ lists.url }}</a></td>
            <td>
                <button id="opener">View</button>
            </td>
        </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
 </div>
```